# Symfony2: Best practise for large forms

Tags: forms, model, symfony, entity

I going to set up some large forms with up to 100 fields.

Now my question is if there is some best practise about handling such forms.

Especially:

1. Entity relations
2. Form object it self

Does somebody have experience about such tasks?
Should I put all together in one entity, one form, structured with jQuery in subforms or should I group the attributes to arrays as much as possible?

Regards,
Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas official documentation show many examples of forms directly linked to entities, I think this is not the best approach. In rare case it's good, when your form has exactly the same fields as your entity.

Your form must represent what you get in the browser, so only html inputs/textearea/select. I usually create a formData class, like an entity, that holds validation constraints and has the same structure as the form.

You have to initialize this formData object with your persisted datas before loading the form, and after submission, you update your entities with your formData object...

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what the benefits are of this solution?
Or do you mean that the formData has all attributes and this gets mapped to ordered attributes of the entity?

Comment: My FormData object is mapped on the Form, not on the Entity. It knows how to set up its properties from given entity/ies

Answer (score 1):

I am creating some complex forms that are built from multiple entities. I [create a form class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) for each entity and then create a composite form class that holds the various combinations of forms I need (which is in someways similar to PéCé's suggestion).

If I don't need all of the fields, that is fine because I can control which fields are rendered in the twig template. If I need fields that aren't in the form class, I can add them to the template and process the form data as appropriate. For all of this effort I get some built in validation and flexibility to reuse forms from multiple entities and bundles.

Comment: Hi, I don't need a FormTyleClass. This is what I am already using. My question is how I can keep entities/forms with many attributes as simple as possible. One suggestion would be to group the attributes and save sub attributes in an array. Now I am interested how other handle this issue